# Understanding Unix File Attributes

Tags: unix, file-permissions

I've read the [Unix man pages](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/chmod/) on this subject and searched far and wide, but one thing eludes me. What the heck is the meaning of the number between the group owner and date?

-rw-r--r--@ 1 Mira  staff  hidden **309** Apr 14 22:00 topsecret.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is the size of the file in bytes.

Comment: Remember that is a LOGICAL number not the physical number of bytes that the file occupies on disk.